# Ubuntu 16.04 unity faild to load

Tags: drivers, unity

I am a beginner in Ubuntu 16.04. Read almost every similar post but cannot find a permanent solution. My graphic card settings:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fda80000-fdabffff ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Almost every time i boot, launcher bar is missing. When i reboot the system almost every time  is fine. I applied almost every solution i found here but with as i said no permanent solution. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Just the launcher you doen't have? Top panel appears?

Comment: yes top panel  appears

Comment: So press ctrl-alt-T and type 'unity --replace'.  What do you have?

Comment: As i said , what you suggest among others is what i have done to retrieve launcher with success. My problem is that when i reboot the problem occurs again

Comment: Look if helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/527383/change-default-route-to-dhcp-interface-without-a-route-push